# About the .mk extension in NDK

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, android-make

I'm about starting an NDK project and I want to explore every thing in a NDK project's scheme.
The reason why I'm wondering, what does .mk mean in Android NDK world ? 
Has some an idea of what it could be ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`.mk` is a standard extension for files designed to be included in Makefiles

Answer (score 1):

Basically Android.mk is used for defining the modules to be compiled, along with the source files and flags to be used during the compilation. Application.mk is used to define for which platforms and architectures the code should be compiled, where the output files should be generated, which modules should be compiled etc. Here is a good tutorial that will get you started with NDK project scheme and using Android.mk. After all that, Application.mk is not hard to follow. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/